# Connection to pypi.python.org timed out

Tags: python, chef-infra, rhel

i am managing a rhel server 6.x which have the Python-2.7.8 installed for an application. When the below chef resource is executed by the chef-client.

```
execute "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 #{node[:base_dir]}/get-pip.py"
```

I see the below error in the chef-client log.

```
[2015-02-24T17:42:27+00:00] ERROR: execute[/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /opt/mount/get-pip.py] (python_app::default line 105) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /opt/mount1/get-pip.py ----
STDOUT: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152ee268d0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152ee269d0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152ee26ad0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152ee26bd0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152ee26cd0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152ee26f50>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152efc4150>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152efc4250>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152efc4350>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f152efc4450>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Collecting pip
  No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
STDERR: 
---- End output of /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /opt/mount1/get-pip.py ----
```

I am looking up python for this issue. I noticed that there is another version of python. i think this comes with the rhel install.

```
Python 2.6.6
```

The python 2.7.8 was install using chef as below:

```
ark 'python' do
  url 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.tgz'
  path "/opt/mount/"
  owner 'python'
  action :put
end

execute "cd #{node[:base_dir]}/python && ./configure && make && make altinstall" do
  not_if { File.exists?('/usr/local/bin/python2.7') }
end
```

One thing that i observed is the '/opt/mount/python' is owned by 'root' as against 'python' user.

Any idea why this error messages?

Comment: I am not offended to see my question being marked down. but i would like to know what research efforts needs to be document in a question. Python is not something that i dealt with. And i have done my best to make the question as elaborate and clear as possible. Marking down a question and giving a hint is a better way to show that we know what and why we are marking down.

Comment: You node obviously seems not to use the proxy. But I don't see a line for the get-pip execution there .. is it part of the `make altinstall` ?

Comment: @Tensibai : the execute in chef is only the execute resource.  execute "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 #{node[:basedir]}/get-pip.py"     Do you suggest to append the proxy info in this command?? like so:    "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 #{node[:basedir]}/get-pip.py --proxy="[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port""

Comment: I would add the proxy information with the environment attribute of the execute resource. If you can edit to show your full recipe I may give a better answer tomorrow (not right now from phone, sorry)

Comment: @Tensibai: adding the proxy in the "execute" chef resource fixed the issue. Now the daemon initiated chef-client runs are successful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

The issue was resolved by specifying the proxy info in the execute resource itself as below:

execute "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 #{node[:base_dir]}/get-pip.py --proxy=http://web-proxy.myorganization.com:8080"