# Not able to install python modules such as pip,selenium etc

Tags: python

Connectivity to pypi.org is blocked in corporate windows laptop hence not able to install pip,selenium etc... Is there any other way to achieve this?

ERROR

> H:\script>python get-pip.py Collecting pip   Retrying (Retry(total=4,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out.
>   (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/ Operation cancelled by user

Comment: May be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155407/connection-to-pypi-python-org-timed-out will help you

Comment: add a proxy to the pip install command, Ex: `pip install packagename --proxy proxyserver:portnumber`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have installed it using proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proxy to install python packages on corporate servers behind firewall.

something like this:

`pip install --proxy www-proxy.xxxxxxx.com:8080 psutil`